make the mobile navigation letter larger size in wordpress theme twenty twenty four
I need help with this site. I’ve been trying to make the mobile navigation larger but the letters are still small no matter what. What could i be doing wrong this is one of my css codes that i found in another forum.
.wp-block-navigation .wp-block-navigation_responsive-container.is-menu-open{
font-size: 50px;!important}
The px is not the real one i just wanted something big to see the difference.
The page I need help with:
any ideas?
I used a plugin wpcode to add css but nothing. I tried additional css but still nothing.

You need to apply in Media Queries.
Also you missed took wrong class wp-block-navigation_responsive-container
Please try this
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .wp-block-navigation .wp-block-navigation__responsive-container.is-menu-open .has-medium-font-size {
        font-size: 50px !important;
    }
}

